# prove that $\frac{|z-a|}{|\overline{a}z-1|}=1$ if |z|=1 and a $\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I started with that: $\frac{|z-a|}{|\overline{a}z-1|}=\frac{|(z-a)(\overline{\overline{a}z} -1)|}{|\overline{a}z-1|^2}=\frac{|a|z|^2 - z -a^2\overline{z} +a|}{|\overline{a}z-1|^2}= \frac{|a^2\overline{z}-2a+z|}{|\overline{a}z-1|^2} = ..?$ How to prove this equality with 1?

Comment: Prove what? Your question is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Since $|z|=1$, $|\bar{a}z-1|=|\bar{a}-1/z|=|\bar{a}-\bar{z}|=|z-a|$. The ratio is undefined if $a=z$; otherwise, it's $1$.

Comment: Why can we write that: $\frac{1}{z} = \overline{z}$?

Comment: @Mia By definition, $|z|=\sqrt{z\bar{z}}$.

Comment: thanks for help :)